# Issue Looping Through an entire list in power query

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am pulling data from the internet right now and formatting it into a readable list using power query, but I am running into an issue. When I split the columns into rows (as I have to change the data from columns to rows for it to be more easily read) I am having to do it manually with a formula like the one below.

This works fine for when I only have 195 records or less however some of the data sets I have contain over 600 records and one contains over 2700 records so I am wondering if there is any way to loop through the columns instead of manually creating a list like the one above because typing out an extra 2000+ items would not be worth it. If anyone needs to see the entire PQ formula I can share that as well, thank you!

= Table.SplitColumn(rc1, "list", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("=", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"list.1", "list.2", "list.3", "list.4", "list.5", "list.6", "list.7", "list.8", "list.9", "list.10", "list.11", "list.12", "list.13", "list.14", "list.15", "list.16", "list.17", "list.18", "list.19", "list.20", "list.21", "list.22", "list.23", "list.24", "list.25", "list.26", "list.27", "list.28", "list.29", "list.30", "list.31", "list.32", "list.33", "list.34", "list.35", "list.36", "list.37", "list.38", "list.39", "list.40", "list.41", "list.42", "list.43", "list.44", "list.45", "list.46", "list.47", "list.48", "list.49", "list.50", "list.51", "list.52", "list.53", "list.54", "list.55", "list.56", "list.57", "list.58", "list.59", "list.60", "list.61", "list.62", "list.63", "list.64", "list.65", "list.66", "list.67", "list.68", "list.69", "list.70", "list.71", "list.72", "list.73", "list.74", "list.75", "list.76", "list.77", "list.78", "list.79", "list.80", "list.81", "list.82", "list.83", "list.84", "list.85", "list.86", "list.87", "list.88", "list.89", "list.90", "list.91", "list.92", "list.93", "list.94", "list.95", "list.96", "list.97", "list.98", "list.99", "list.100", "list.101", "list.102", "list.103", "list.104", "list.105", "list.106", "list.107", "list.108", "list.109", "list.110", "list.111", "list.112", "list.113", "list.114", "list.115", "list.116", "list.117", "list.118", "list.119", "list.120", "list.121", "list.122", "list.123", "list.124", "list.125", "list.126", "list.127", "list.128", "list.129", "list.130", "list.131", "list.132", "list.133", "list.134", "list.135", "list.136", "list.137", "list.138", "list.139", "list.140", "list.141", "list.142", "list.143", "list.144", "list.145", "list.146", "list.147", "list.148", "list.149", "list.150", "list.151", "list.152", "list.153", "list.154", "list.155", "list.156", "list.157", "list.158", "list.159", "list.160", "list.161", "list.162", "list.163", "list.164", "list.165", "list.166", "list.167", "list.168", "list.169", "list.170", "list.171", "list.172", "list.173", "list.174", "list.175", "list.176", "list.177", "list.178", "list.179", "list.180", "list.181", "list.182", "list.183", "list.184", "list.185", "list.186", "list.187", "list.188", "list.189", "list.190", "list.191", "list.192", "list.193", "list.194", "list.195"})

Answer (score 0):

It is hard for me to visualize exactly what you are doing without data or code, but to create the list you show in your question, you can use this M-Code:

```
List.Transform(List.Numbers(1,195), each "list." & Text.From(_))
```

It should be possible to compute the upper bound from your original data, or you can just hard-code it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to include the column names at all. If you leave it blank, PQ will use the 'list.1, list.2...' format for all columns.

From: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-splitcolumn

"Table.SplitColumn(table as table, sourceColumn as text, splitter as function, **optional columnNamesOrNumber as any**, optional default as any, optional extraColumns as any) as table"

So you can just use:

```
= Table.SplitColumn(rc1, "list", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("=", QuoteStyle.Csv))
```

Also you mentioned you want to split columns into rows, but your code looks like it is splitting a column into multiple columns. There is an option to split a column to rows, if that is what you want to do:

[image]

Comment: I actually found this out by accident when messing with the query code myself. thank you! I have a step after this that turns all the columns into rows as well